# unity Rigidbody jump

Tags: unity, rigid-body-dynamics

I absolutely don't know what is the problem with this code and I have tried everything without any success. I need help.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.localPosition+new Vector3(0f,0.1f,0f),-transform.up,0.2f) ) 
        {
            grounded = true;
        } else
            grounded = false;

if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump") && grounded)

            {
                rb.velocity+= Vector3.up*jumpSpeed;

            }
}
```

Some time it jumps and some time it doesn't jump with no visible pattern.

Comment: Have you tried to spam the debug console each frame to output what were the condition states (i.e. if the button is down at the same time the position is grounded)? Still today, spamming the console is the most used way to debug code.

Comment: Thanks, it was because the grounded. i used another method (OnCollisionEnter) in witch i checked  for the y coordinates of the contact point to see if grounded.